# Clan I play two separate clash of clans bases on my ipad?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I have clash of clans on my android phone and would like to also play it (same base) on my ipad. Except I already have clash of clans on my ipad with game center account and would also like to keep and play that different base. Is there a way I can play both on my ipad?

Comment: tl;dr: no you can't.

Comment: I think you can only do that on android

Answer (score -2):

### Make sure you have your account backed-up

This is going hand and hand to what @ModDL is saying...  If you go under settings and then under apps tap Clash of Clans.
There should be a button that says clear data. Tap it!  Then run Clash of Clans, you should see the tutorial village, Tap the Log-In button.  If you have two accounts set up to your tablet it should ask you which one you want to use.  Then all you need to do is tap the Load button